# Array rotation with python (90 degree clockwise)- Having issues with understanding list copies

Tags: python, arrays

> Hi, I am new to python need help with making list copies!

```
def rotate(lst):
    a=lst[:] 
#a=lst[:] / =lst.copy() / =[x for x in lst] e.t.c does not work but a=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] works # # # how? 
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst)):
            a[j][i]=lst[len(lst)-i-1][j]
    return a
lst=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

print(rotate(lst))
print(lst)
```

> Expected answer (obtained when a=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]):

```
[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

> Answer obtained when using
> a=lst[:] |  a =lst.copy() | a =[x for x in lst]

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[7, 8, 7], [8, 5, 8], [9, 6, 7]]
[[7, 8, 7], [8, 5, 8], [9, 6, 7]]
```

> a=[[0]*len(lst)]*len(lst) gives a wrong answer too even though it essentially means a=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[9, 6, 3], [9, 6, 3], [9, 6, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

> Why does this happen? why does the deep copy not work in this case?

Comment: what is your question? do you have any problem with your code?

Comment: Yes, I am unable to make deep copies that when manipulated do not change the list passed into the function.

Comment: you can use deep copy. normal copy doen't work for ndimensional lists

Comment: a=lst[:]  or a =lst.copy() or  a =[x for x in lst] does not work